# IMDB App Image slider

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

If you have installed the IMDB app and watched the animation of the attached image. I am wondering if it's a view pager or a horizontal list view or what ? And is there any library that has this view with its animation ? Any recommendations will be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use ViewPager with views/fragment (this depends on screens details). To create beautiful transitions between screens use ViewPager.PagerTransformer. Connect it to TabLayout.

But if you still want to use RecyclerView it also possible in it.

Good luck.